# iPhone and Android: Is it possible to have an app that listens at all times?

Tags: iphone, android, xcode, audio

...and when listens at an specific sound it activates an action?
For example: 
An app that sends a Push Notification when an specific sound is listened in the environment.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible, and for good reasons:

- Security, one could write an app that snoops on people in the background
- Battery life

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine just created an iOS demo that runs in the background, listens to audio and sends messages via network to something else.

And this is indeed working very well. As far as I know everything was built with official frameworks and without jailbreaking.
Although I'm not sure if this app would be allowed in the app store, it uses background processing for audio apps, and I don't know if such a thing fits this category. I guess we'll try it soon.

The snooping mentioned by Zoran can only happen if you hide the iOS device in their pocket because there will be a red status bar that tells you that something is recording in the background.

Comment: fluchtpunkt that is helpful and hopeful... I still wonder if its possible to send a Push Notification when a specific sound is listened in the environment...
Can you put me in contact with your friend, probably he can help me build the app?

Comment: I hope they plug this security hole. Imagine a phone left in a meeting room, apparently idle, but recording/transmitting.

Comment: @Gueri I'm sorry but I think you can't afford his hourly rates.

Comment: @Phil don't let untrustworthy people into your meeting room. You can get recording devices that are smaller and less obvious for $100 at Best Buy.

Comment: doesn't my nickname sound expensive? I may afford his hourly rate, please don't hesitate and send me his info if he's interested, of course. My email: gueri@detour.co